# Debugging symbols for CUFFT and CUDA Runtime API (cudart)

Tags: debugging, cuda, cuda-gdb

Where I can find `*.debug` file with debugging info for CUDA libraries from CUDA SDK, namely CUFFT and CUDA Runtime API (cudart), and how to provide them to debugger and/or profiler?

Without this info debugging application that uses CUDA libraries is very difficult, especially when the error is in CUDA code.

Answer (score 3):

These libraries are not open source, and so naturally debug symbols are not provided.

If you find that there is a bug in a library, I recommend you [become a registered CUDA developer](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-registered-developer-program) and report the issue using the online bug report form. Alternatively (but less preferably), report the issue in more detail here or on the [NVIDIA forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showforum=62).

Before you report a bug, make sure you are confident it is not in your own code first. :)

Comment: I'd have to check, but the problem seems to be that in 4.0.x `cufftPlanMany` doesn't work with C2R and R2C transformations, even without advanced features like non-1 stride (the documentation was not clear on this issue... nb. why nVidia stopped providing online documentation to old versions?).  This is **supposedly** fixed in 4.1.x, but I have to check this.